# Is a bad practice to monkey patch a base ruby class?

Tags: ruby, monkeypatching

I'm working on a ruby project in which we are planning to do some operations with ruby strings. Some operations are simple (like counting the number of words) and others more complex (like checking if a given string is in the correct language).

A possible way to implement this is by patching the `String` class with extra methods, **without modifying any existing methods**, and adding behaviors like `"some string".word_count` and `"some string".cjk?`.

Another approach, based on `FileUtils` is to create a class or module full of methods and always use string as parameters, like `OddClassName.word_count("some string")` and `OddClassName.cjk?("some string")`. We like the first better because of readability.

I understand that monkey patching a basic class as described in the first alternative can have name clashes. However, if this is the main application, not a library, should I worry with it at all?

So, the questions are:

- Is adding methods to ruby base classes a bad practice? If yes, is that in all cases or only in some cases?
- What is the best approach to accomplish this?
- What could be the name of 'OddClassName'?

Please suggest any alternatives.

Comment: Which version of Ruby are you using? I believe there are some different monkey patching options in 2.0

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell I'm using 1.9, but feel free to add 2.0 in your answer as well if it fits.

Comment: You don't need to use the headers to mark sections in your question. The StackOverflow look and feel is a bit more conversational and less formal. Remove the headers and your question will flow very nicely. Be sure to capitalize proper names for things like "Ruby" though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Monkey patching isn't considered to be a bad practice unless you are writing odd methods that do not have PatchedClass-related behavior (for example, `String.monkeyPatchForMakingJpegFromString` is rather bad, but `Jpeg.fromString` is good enough.)

But if your project is rather large, the libraries that you use in it may happen to have colliding patches, so you may have one more problem with all these patching stuffs. In Ruby 2.0, **refinements** come to an aid. They work as follows: you define a `module`, `refine` your (even core) class in it, and then use that module where it's necessary. So, in your code it works as:

```
YourClass.new.refinedMethodFromCoreClass #=> some result
```

But

```
CoreClass.refinedMethodFromCoreClass
```

produces `undefined method` exception.

That's all monkey patching stuff: monkey patching is useful and convenient, but refinements add some features, that make your code more secure, maintainable and neat.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you have any reference for this: "Monkey patching, basically, isn't considered to be a bad practice" Applied to base classes?

Comment: [interview w/ matz](http://fredwu.me/post/36493181321/an-interview-with-yukihiro-matz-matsumoto), 6th answer:

Comment: Thanks, it appears that he tells that you can extend base classes, but did not told us that is a good practice. Taking this in consideration anyway.

Comment: I don't know whether you'll find it sufficient, but Rails do use it, too. All these 10.hours and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a new class, call it `Doc` or something because getting the word count and checking languages sounds like operations for documents.

Let it take a string as a constructor parameter and have modifications chain to return a new Doc. Also give it a to_s method that returns the string.

```
class Doc
  def initialize(str)
    @str = str
  end

  def to_s
    @str
  end

  define word_count, cjk?, etc.
end

Doc.new("Some document").word_count
# => 2
```